# Set up an offline database in file structure and access it with Javascript

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite

I have a question that might seem a bit vague and that is because Im not sure the best way to proceed.

I have a HTML page that I need to be able to run offline. I need it to collect and be able to edit/delete info from a database, and I need that database to be situated somewhere in the computers local network files. Im not sure which route to go down for this to work.

I have looked into saving the data as a .json file, but then the data cant be changed/deleted by the browser.

I have looked into using the browsers local storage but what I need is for when the database is updated on one computer using the local network, it needs to show the update on other computers connected to the same network. Local storage only works for one instance of the browser, as far as I can tell, the local storage cannot be shared to other computers.

I have looked into using SQLite, but I cant use php, because then I take it I need a testing server to be able to see the page. I could set up something like WAMP but Id prefer not to have to start that before the page can be opened. Also Im not sure if that can be accessed from other computers.

I have looked into using SQLite and access it with javascript using SQL.js. This is my prefered method at the moment, but it seems that it stores the database to system memory instead of within the local networks file structure, and I assume that cant be reached by other computers on the network.

Anybody have any ideas for a way to make this work?